# How do I build Testcafe so that I can contribute to it?

Tags: build, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

My long term goal is to contribute functionality to Testcafe.  Immediately, I'm trying to include it in my current node project so that I can see the changes.  I've done the following so far.

1. Forked the Testcafe repo
2. npm linked the forked repo to my current project https://medium.com/@alexishevia/the-magic-behind-npm-link-d94dcb3a81af
3. changed the package.json file's main entry to src/index instead of lib/index
4. When I npm run dev in my project I hit this error (no problems including the actual npm installation of testcafe)

`import { GeneralError } from './errors/runtime';`
       ^

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:23)`

My assumption (likely the impetus of my problem) based on this error is that I need the "built" version of testcafe (via npm run build). Unfortunately, npm run build isn't a script available in the testcafe repo, and I can't figure out how to do it otherwise.

What I've tried:

- running the available npm scripts
- reading gulp documentation, hoping it was gulp based

I'm in high friction scenario here, which is usually a sign that I've missed a crucial detail and I'm not even close to the right path.

Answer (score 1):

To build TestCafe, execute the `gulp build` command from the fork root directory. It will build TestCafe into the `lib` folder.

UPD: In addition, refer to the [Contributing to TestCafe](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) page, which contains all information you may need to start contributing to TestCafe: Code of Conduct, build/test instructions, and more.